# Arc menu hot key not working while having windows opend

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, arc-menu

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04. I noticed that if I minimize all windows and press the hot key (Window key) Arc menu gets open.

But if any of program window is floating on screen then pressing the hot key does not opens the arc menu.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

**Re-post of the issue on ArcMenu's issue tracker link below.**

**Issue 128 -** https://gitlab.com/LinxGem33/Arc-Menu/issues/128

Hi

Appreciate the feedback, we are aware of this issue and have investigated and believe its an upstream issue with gnome-shell 3.34 as this is the only version of gnome-shell which is affected by this issue, specifically on the xorg session we are now currently investigating a workaround for this issue hope this helps.

gnome-shell issue - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1722

kind regards

---

**Work Around..**

**edit**: Workaround now !109 (merged) in v33 development.

Users now have the option to choose to trigger the menu on key release or key press.

The workaround for gnome 3.34 and this issue is to choose key press in ArcMenu 
settings until the gnome developers fix this issue/bug upstream.

Comment: This workaround will cripple your use of <kbd>Super</kbd> as modifier key (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to tile left).

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting pressing and releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to a different key combination. By default, Arc menu can also be summoned with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (I believe, but I cannot test it as I do not have Gnome currently, so if you try, please provide feedback so the answer can be adjusted).

**Procedure**

1) Change the hotkey of Arc Menu to something else, e.g. Right <kbd>Super</kbd>, or disable it if possible.

2) Disable Gnome Shell's use of <kbd>Super</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

3) With a tool like `xcape` (install using `sudo apt install xcape`), you can redirect pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> to any key combination, in this case the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination.

```
xcape -e "Super_L=Alt_L|F1"
```

Include that command in your autostart programs. If that does not work, include a small delay as: `sh -c 'sleep 0.5 && xcape -e "Super_L=Alt_L|F1"'`.

**Possible issue with Arc menu resetting the `overlay-key` setting on start up**

Thus far the theory, and it actually may work directly with more recent versions of Arc. Unfortunately, it may also still be so that Arc menu hard sets the `overlay-key` setting even if you changed the key in Arc to another one, and changed org.gnome.mutter yourself. Bad programming practice, causing the need for more workarounds. In that case, you could work with an autostart script that kicks in action a few seconds after login (`sleep`) and then resets `overlay-key` and loads `xcape` after Arc menu has initialized.